# how do you check if a string has more than one specific character in python. Example The string, 'mood' would clearly have two 'o' characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

how do you  check if a string has more than one specific character in python. Example The string, 'mood' would clearly have  two 'o' characters

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `str.count` method:

```
>>> 'mood'.count('o') > 1
True
>>>
```